# Best practices for writing a Java library in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am planning on writing a library that will primarily be consumed from Java. However, I would like to write this in Scala. I have read most of the documentation on Java/Scala interop, but it is mostly focused on using existing libraries, rather than best practices to ensure seamless interop when *writing* libraries.

What are some ways of doing this effectively? Ideally, the consumers would not know the library was written in Scala at all.

Are there any other major libraries that do this?

My current plan is to have an API that exposes everything needed with Scala types/features, then having a smaller layer on top of this that converts to Java types. Are there any issues with this approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any reason you would want to do this?  It's one thing to write a Scala library that can also be used from Scala, but if you want to target Java specifically it probably just makes sense to use Java to write the library.

> Ideally, the consumers would not know the library was written in Scala at all.

The biggest issues with this is going to be transient dependencies.  Even if you use no third party libraries from yours, what about the Scala standard library?  If your library would be used in a project that wasn't otherwise using Scala, they would need to pull in the entire Scala library as well unless you don't use the standard lib at all in your code.

You are going to want to use Java collections instead of Scala collections, and  since that's what your client code will be expecting.  You should have no Scala Standard Library classes in your public interface. This also means use Java Functional Interfaces instead of Scala Function Types

Avoid companion objects except for situations where they compile down to static members on a class.  Accessing a Scala companion object from Java is cumbersome.

Use Java Bean conventions for getters/setters/case classes instead of the regular Scala properties (I believe Scala has an annotation for this).

As far as existing libraries, the [Spark Java API](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/1a870090e4266df570c3f56c1e2ea12d090d03d1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java) is written in Scala, but Spark is primary build for Scala with some Java support, but maybe worth looking at (especially to see the differences between the Scala and Java apis.

Comment: I think there are valid reasons for this: Spark does it, as you mention. To me, it arose from needing to work with Akka Streams (much easier to code in Scala), but to support Java projects using such library.

Answer (score 0):

The only concerns I found are needing to included the Scala runtime library, and to append `_2.13` to the artifact names.

By publishing via Maven (`sbt publishM2`), even the Scala library comes automatically to the downstream project.